# How to convert to NTZ timestamp in Snowflake from a string with a timezone?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am running into a weird problem. I have a timestamp string column which has values like `2022-08-03T21:08:45.164Z` and a timezone column with values like `America/New_York`. I have a separate table where I have the dates field in NTZ format. Is there a way for me to convert the above string and timezone to an NTZ formatted date in Snowflake?

Thanks!

I tried using

```
TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(TO_VARCHAR(column_name))
```

and that is resulting in a weird date format number. Is there a way for me to pass in locale/timezone to the method and then convert it back to NTZ format?

Comment: Do you expect your NTZ timestamp to have the +/- hours added from the TZ one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use CONVERT_TIMEZONE function?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html

Let's assume your target timezone is UTC. In this case, you can use it like this:

```
create table d_test ( d varchar, tz varchar  ) 
as select '2022-08-03T21:08:45.164Z', 'America/New_York';
    
select CONVERT_TIMEZONE( tz, 'UTC', d ) res from d_test;

+-------------------------+
|           RES           |
+-------------------------+
| 2022-08-04 01:08:45.164 |
+-------------------------+
```